# Errors as I reopen projects on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I try to reopen an existing project using the method of  Use File > Import and select General > Existing Projects into Workspace Click next and then browse to the directory contain the project directory. `{as per cited on this webpage}`, I keep getting errors like Failed to find style `buttonStyle` in current theme and many more. I am new to android app programing